# Deploy django project with celery

Tags: python, celery, django-celery

After I deploy my django project, all I need is *touch uwsgi_touch* file. And uwsgi will gracefully restart its workers. But what about celery? Now I just restart celery manually when code base of celery tasks is changed. But even if I do it manually I still can't be sure that I will not kill celery task.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found answer in celery FAQ
http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/2.2/faq.html#how-do-i-shut-down-celeryd-safely

> Use the TERM signal, and the worker will finish all currently
>   executing jobs and shut down as soon as possible. No tasks should be
>   lost.
>
> You should never stop celeryd with the KILL signal (-9), unless you’ve
>   tried TERM a few times and waited a few minutes to let it get a chance
>   to shut down. As if you do tasks may be terminated mid-execution, and
>   they will not be re-run unless you have the acks_late option set
>   (Task.acks_late / CELERY_ACKS_LATE).

Answer (score 2):

A better way to manage celery workers is to use `supervisor`

```
$ pip install supervisor
$ cd /path/to/your/project
$ echo_supervisord_conf > supervisord.conf
```

Add these to your `supervisord.conf` file

```
[program:celeryworker]
command=/path/to/celery worker -A yourapp -l info 
stdout_logfile=/path/to/your/logs/celeryd.log
stderr_logfile=/path/to/your/logs/celeryd.log
```

Now start supervisor with `supervisord` command in your terminal & use `supervisorctl` to manage process.

To restart you can do

```
$ supervisorctl restart celeryworker
```

Comment: Yeah, thanks for your answer. We already use supervisor for that purpose. But the question is a bit different. I don't know how to safely deploy new version of our product. If i understand it right the celery worker and bit-scheduler need to be restarted if celery tasks was changed (code of tasks was changed). And it will be bad if i kill celery worker that process some task in production while i restarting celery.